# Fitting JSON strings to an Angular class for front end?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, websocket, constructor

I don't understand how data gets broken into key value pairs in Angular using a constructor per event.

Here's my code:

```
  messageFromSocket: keywordList[] = [];
  wsSubscription: Subscription;
  status;

  constructor(public webSocketService: WebSocketService) {
    this.wsSubscription = this.webSocketService.createObservableSocket('ws://localhost:3000')
      .subscribe(
        messages => this.messageFromSocket.push(
          messages
          ),
        err => console.log('err'),
        () => console.log('The observable stream is complete')
      )
  }
```

This is my `component.ts` minus a few things. Essentially, how I have it working now is that when a websocket event comes in, it pushes automatically to this `messageFromSocket` `keywordList` array.

The `KeywordList` array is actually its' own class in another file with a constructor inside of it.

```
  name: string;
  keyword: string;
   constructor(name: string, keyword: string) { 
     this.name = name;
     this.keyword = keyword;
  }
}
```

It's being displayed on the front end but as it's own large array.

```
  <ng-container class="keywordBox" *ngFor='let message of messageFromSocket'>
      <li>
        {{ message }}
      </li>
  </ng-container>
```

I can't seem to grasp the concept of how to manipulate the string data coming in from the websocket to create a key value pair of a name and a keyword (both are being sent each time by the websocket without fail), and then display it on the front end like in many of the examples. I would like this so I can better manipulate the data through out the application.

For example, right now it comes through to look like:

```
['George: Hello']
or
['George: Hello', 'Raul: World']
```

I'd like to use the `KeywordList` class to break them out.

Also, if you know how to add padding to just the first item in dynamic content, could you please help me as I feel like I've tried every CSS trick Angular has and I'm still missing something.

Comment: Please explain the `keywordList` constructor and how it is being used with the String that is the message from the socket server. I don's see where you are instantiating that class in this code.

Comment: I don't think I am and that's part of the problem. I don't really know where or how I would add it. I want to create the structure but how I get from the websocket event to key value pairs is confusing to me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this changes:

```
export class KeywordList {  
   constructor(public name: string, public keyword: string) {}
}
```

---

```
constructor(public webSocketService: WebSocketService) {
    this.wsSubscription = this.webSocketService.createObservableSocket('ws://localhost:3000')
      .subscribe(
        messages => {

           messages.forEach(
              (message)=> {
                 const arrayMessage = message.split(':');
                 const name = arrayMessage[0];
                 const keyword = arrayMessage[1].trim();

                 const keywordList: KeywordList = new KeywordList(name,keyword);


                 this.messageFromSocket.push(keywordList);

           }),      
           err => console.log('err'),
           () => console.log('The observable stream is complete')
      );

}
```

Comment: This gives me a block scope error on 

```const keywordList: KeywordList = new KeywordList (name,keyword); ``` 

specifically with the new keywordList.

Comment: I guess it was because it had 1 space between, I edited the answer.Try now (and don't forget to capitalize KeywordList) in this way: new KeywordList(name,keyword);

Comment: Sorry I fixed it up a bit and now it's throwing out that ForEach is not a function. I'll give an update as I work through it I guess

Comment: So I am still struggling with this. I've tried to use your solution as provided but keep getting weird errors BUT you did help me understand how I am supposed to approach creating the KeywordList. I did get it to to my HTML component but the data comes through as object Object and the array displays keywordList{name: keyword:} for EACH message. Meaning it looks like [keywordList, keywordList, keywordList] with each keywordList displaying a name and keyword. I was hoping for just 1. Any advice would be appreciated.